# function combining infinitisimal

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

i have one big question that i want to know if i solved right, if i did wrong, please correct me and show me the right way to solve so i'll be able to learn.

Let f, g, h functions from R -> R
prove or disprove:
1) if f * g = f * h, then g=h. 
my answer no, because even if the images equal there might be other values in g or h that might be not defined if f.

2)if f * g = g * h and f is injective(one-to-one) then g=h. 
here i said it's right because it's well defined and i don't think neither h or g might have values that are not in f(g) or f(h).

3)if g * f = h * f and f is supreme then g=h (function A -> B is called supreme if we can obtain B as a result of the function, wasn't sure if its name).
Here i am not really sure, but i think it's true because it's well defined you can get it's image from only one member of the domain, so i think it's true.

4)if f*g is rising, and f is going down so g is going down. 
i think it's true, because if we mark it using f(g(t), then if it's rising it's only if both are positive or both negative ((-t)*(-t)).

5)if f * g i rising, and f is injective, then g monotonous. 
Here i am not sure, but i think it's false since being injective doesn't say a lot about f(g(x) to help us deduct that g is monotonous.

thank you very much for your help. hoping to learn from your answer and to understand this concept. if you can elaborate or correct me, it'll be very helpful. plus, i am sure others might profit from this.

note:by * i mean function combining, so f * g = f(g(x)).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer of 1) is correct.

But for 2), it isn't. Assume that f(x)=x^2 and g(x)=x+1. Then f(g(x))=(x+1)^2, but g(f(x))=x^2+1, which are not the same.

Your answer of 3), 4) and 5) are probably true, but for 4), the word *both* should refer to the first derivative, not the original function.

Comment: thank you for correcting 2.

is 5 correct? if not please correct me so i'll be able to learn from my mistakes and improve.